# Keycloak and postgres docker compose

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I built this compose stack to run keycloak and associate a postgres DB:

```
volumes:
  postgres_data:
    driver: local
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14.1-alpine
    volumes:
      - path
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: test1
      POSTGRES_USER: ex
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ex
    ports:
      - '5433:5432'

  keycloak:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak
    volumes:
      - path
    environment:
      DB_VENDOR: POSTGRES
      DB_ADDR: postgres
      DB_DATABASE: test1
      DB_USER: ex
      DB_PASSWORD: ex
      DB_SCHEMA: public
      KEYCLOAK_USER: 'something'
      KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD: 'something'
    command:
      - start-dev
      - --import-realm
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
```

To run this stack:

```
docker compose up
```

note: the values used in here are examples

I was trying to see the tables in the DB and I didn't find any. The docker is running without any error logs... So I'm a bit lost...

Comment: What do you have `path` in your postgres `volumes` key rather than your `postgres_data` volume?

Comment: What tool are you using to inspect PostgreSQL? Your database is called `test1` and some multi-engine GUI programs many not expect/support connections to anything but the default `postgres` one.

Comment: @larks volumes:- path key is this way for the sake of this example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This demo will see Keycloak's database table.

I am using `Keycloak` version 23.0.7 and `postgres` version 15.6

And git bash termina in Windows

In docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15.6
    container_name: postgres_db
    volumes:
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: keycloak
      POSTGRES_USER: keycloak
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password

  keycloak_web:
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.7
    container_name: keycloak_web
    environment:
      KC_DB: postgres
      KC_DB_URL: jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: password

      KC_HOSTNAME: localhost
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT: false
      KC_HOSTNAME_STRICT_HTTPS: false

      KC_LOG_LEVEL: info
      KC_METRICS_ENABLED: true
      KC_HEALTH_ENABLED: true
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
    command: start-dev
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    ports:
      - 8180:8080

volumes:
  postgres_data:
```

Launching it

```bash
docker compose up
```

[image]

##### Step #1 Check containers

```
docker ps -a
```

[image]

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                              COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS                              NAMES
ff2a5f7e4386   quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:23.0.7   "/opt/keycloak/bin/k…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes   8443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8180->8080/tcp   keycloak_web
bcb8cf4e2f2e   postgres:15.6                      "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 minutes ago   Up 4 minutes   5432/tcp                           postgres_db
```

Open browser

```
http://localhost:8180/admin/master/console/
```

[image]

##### Step # 2, go inside `postgres` container

```
winpty docker exec -it postgres_db bin/bash
```

(* note: I am using Windows git bash, winpty is not need in Linux)

[image]

##### Step #3, check Linux version

```
cat /etc/os-release
```

<kbd>Output</kbd>

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

Who Am I

```
whoami
```

<kbd>Output</kbd>

```
root
```

##### Step #4, add user 'keycloak`and add`sudo` user

```
adduser keycloak
```

(note `password` is password)

<kbd>Output</kbd>

[image]

##### Step #5, switch user `keycloak` and connect database

```
su keycloak
```

```
psql -U keycloak -w
```

<kbd>Output</kbd>

```
psql (15.6 (Debian 15.6-1.pgdg120+2))
Type "help" for help.
```

[image]

##### Step #6, get connected information

```
 \conninfo
```

<kbd>Output</kbd>

[image]

##### Step #7, list tables and schemas

```
\dt
```

<kbd>Output</kbd>

[image]

##### Step #8, clients list and detail information

```
SELECT name, client_id  FROM client;
```

<kbd>Output</kbd>

[image]

It should be matched UI's clients

[image]

##### User data for specific realm

You need to check realm ID

```
SELECT name, id FROM realm;
```

<kbd>Output</kbd>

[image]

Then filter by `realm_id` for `my-realm`'s user list

```
SELECT username, email FROM  user_entity WHERE realm_id='c4e827a1-823a-4304-8905-5daa89563cbe';
```

<kbd>Output</kbd>

[image]

It will return UI's user list for `my-realm`

[image]

Comment: thank you for the example. i did this part:postgres=# \dt
Did not find any relations. but I guess it didn't find any relations... coult it be because Im using a realm in the docker to start keycloak?

Comment: Did you succeed #4/5/6?  `\dt` only available after pass those steps first. Then you can see "keycloak=#" and can run the table list commend. Following step 4~6 again. Try again

Comment: My demo, do not matter  `your realm` has or not. It display master tables list.

Comment: hello @Bench Vue, when you used your realm, could you actually check the user that you just created in the realm?

Comment: @rainbow12, I updated to add `how to get user list for specific realm`, Can you accept my answer?

Comment: @rainbow12, Thank you for your accepting, can you make upvote too?