# HTTP request to keycloak with insommia

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, insomnia

I am creating a secured back-end for a new app with Keycloak and NestJS. I imported my realm with clients and user in it and I am trying to get the token and access protected data through Insomnia.

Trying to reach endpoint `{{ _.baseUrl }}/protocol/openid-connect/auth` with a `POST` request passing data through JSON is returning

```
keycloak-1  | 2024-03-11 16:01:56,436 WARN  [org.keycloak.protocol.oidc.endpoints.request.AuthorizationEndpointRequestParserProcessor] (executor-thread-131) Parameter 'client_id' not present or present multiple times in the HTTP request parameters
keycloak-1  | 2024-03-11 16:01:56,437 WARN  [org.keycloak.events] (executor-thread-131) type="LOGIN_ERROR", realmId="55542514-fc71-4e4e-be3e-42af869de2a7", clientId="null", userId="null", ipAddress="172.18.0.1", error="invalid_request"
```

in my Docker Keycloak logs and a `400 Bad request error` in Insomnia response preview window.

At first I was only passing my credentials and the error made me rethink the whole thing and pass client_id and client_secret as well i the JSON data yet error i still the same.

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.ankursheel.com/blog/automatically-set-access-token-authenticated-requests-insomnia) but it does not seem suitable for a Keycloak environment

How to reach to my Keycloak endpoints via Insomnia and furthermore how to get more verbose logs in the future ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insomina is a little hard.

##### Overview

[image]

#0 Keycloak launching
Detail in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78101985/keycloack-and-postgres-docker-compose/78103098#78103098)

Access Token URL

```
POST "http://localhost:8180/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```

##### How to find Token URL?

[image]

The `token_endpoint` should be match Insomnia `URL PREVIEW`

[image]

If not, `404 not Found Error`

#1  Crete New Collection

[image]

#2  Name as `Keycloak`

[image]

#3 Click Gear Icon for setting

[image]

#4 Base Environment

```json
{
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:8180",
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin",
    "access-token": ""
}
```

[image]

#5  Add HTTP Request

[image]

#6-7  Create `Get-Token` by POST API

[image]

#8  <kbd>CTRL + Space</kbd>
Can add get environment variable

detail in [here](https://docs.insomnia.rest/insomnia/chaining-requests)

[image]

#9 Make URL with an environment variable

```
{{ _.baseUrl }}/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
```

[image]

#10 Add Body key/value by `Form URL Encoded`

[image]

[image]

It is same as `/x-www-form-urlencoded` in Postman

[image]

#11~13 Add 4 keys/value

User name and password get from environmental variable

By <kbd>CTRL + Space</kbd>

[image]

[image]

#14 Get token
Click <kbd>Send</kbd>

##### Result

[image]

##### Bonus

##### How to use an access-token?

Add `Request` Get user list
[image]

#1 Open Base Environment
In the `access-token` place cursor inside ""

<kbd>CTRL+Space</kbd>

Select  `f Response => Body Attribute`

[image]

Result

[image]

#2 Click `reponse 'body', '', '', 'never',60`
[image]

Select: Request `POST Get Token`

[image]

Filter (JSONPath or XPath)

```
$.access_token
```

[image]

Result
[image]

[image]

Finally, get user list with `access-token`

[image]

Comment: I tried this way and this time I got a 404, I edited my question accordingly. I don't think it is an issue with how I use insomnia as it worked fine earlier I was thinking maybe a keycloak config I am missing ?

The bonus you added is fire thank you !

Comment: I update `How to find Token URL?`, The token_endpoint should be match Insomnia URL PREVIEW. If not, 404 error arise. It means the HTTP 404 Not Found response, wrong Token URL.

Comment: Indeed it was a big me problem this morning, can you provide an example to get the userinfo endpoint or should i open an other issue ?

Comment: First Get users list [GET /admin/realms/{realm}/users](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/22.0.1/rest-api/index.html#_users), then get user id(=uuid), get user info by 'GET /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}', If want to more detail, make new question to community, I will help you.

Comment: I don't have users as a valid endpoint apparently

Comment: that means you did not add any user for your realm. Can you check by Keycloak UI for users of your realm? Which version of your Keycloak?